# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a throttling method but I am encountering the error:

> The type arguments for method
> 'Extensions.executeParallelWithReturn(IEnumerable, int, Func<T,
> List, Task>, List)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
> specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public async Task ProcessThrottlingPaymentsByIds(List<List<Guid>> queue, int limit, List<Payment> ts)
{
    await queue.executeParallelWithReturn(limit, GetGenericPaymentsByIds, ts);
}
```

I am encoutering the error here inside the "ProcessThrottlingPaymentsByIds" Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
public static async Task executeParallelWithReturn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int limit, Func<T, List<T>, Task> actionMethod, List<T> ts)
{
    var allTasks = new List<Task>(); //Store all Tasks
    var activeTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (activeTasks.Count >= limit)
        {
            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(activeTasks);
            activeTasks.Remove(completedTask);
        }
        var task = actionMethod(item, ts);
        allTasks.Add(task);
        activeTasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks); // Wait for all task to complete
}
```

Comment: What is GetGenericPaymentsByIds?

Comment: queue is of type `List<List<Guid>>` and your extention method works on `IEnum<T>`. So for that argument `T == List<Guid>`. However you are passing in `ts` which is of type `List<Payment>` so in that case `T == Payment`.

Answer (score 3):

You’re giving it contradicting information here. Let’s see what we have:

```
executeParallelWithReturn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int limit, Func<T, List<T>, Task> actionMethod, List<T> ts)
```

This says there’s only one template argument, so everything will have one type. You call it on the `queue` which is of type `List<List<Guid>>`, which means `T` is of type `List<Guid>` based on the first argument.

But then you give it `ts` of type `List<Payments>` which means `T` should suddenly be of type `Payments`. It can’t be both.

Since the code doesn’t say how a list of guids relates to a `Payments` object I can’t say how to fix it.